# jQuery UI & PHP - Sending 'To' Column to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UIs Sortable to allow a user to move items from 4 columns as well as change the order of items within each column.  I have the latter working without problem; updating the new order to the database.

But I'm not sure how to handle storing moving from Column A to Column B.  Each unordered list has a unique ID so I'd like to send that information along; I just don't have a firm understanding of how to do this.

```
$("#list1, #list2, #list3, #list4").sortable({ 
    connectWith: ".sort",
    placeholder: "shadow", 
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    opacity: 0.8, 
    cursor: 'move', 
    update: function() {
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update';
        $.post("/update.php", order, function(theResponse) {
            $("#alert").html(theResponse);
            $("#alert").slideDown('slow');
            slideout();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: so what are you looking for exactly? it's working, right?

Comment: Right now it is only sending an array with the new sort order (ie. 1,2,3,4,5).  It needs to send an associative array that shows the item being sorted and its new parent UL.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer to my own question.  The answer is to pass the data to the PHP file in a slightly different manner that allows for a more robust amount of variables (rather than just serializing one set of information).

```
var item   = ui.item;
var new_ul = item.parent();
var order  = [];
container.children('li').each(function(i){
    reorder[i] = $(this).attr('id');
});

$.ajax({
    method:'post',
    url: 'update.php',
    data:{
        'new_ul':container.attr('id'),
        'item':item.attr('id'),
        'order':order
    }
});
```

Full credit for this solution goes to user 'Zehee' at CodeIgniter (Who I believe got the solution from 37signals) http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/175134/#831756